# The emulator doesn't respond at all

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just installed Nexus 5 emulator in Android Studio and clicked the Run button. However, the emulator didn't respond at all. Here is the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbOhO.jpg)

My system info:
Windows 10 64bit 21H2
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.4 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Pen support

Comment: The emulator is obviously running, but the project doesn't seem to build, for whatever reason. One may find it difficult to upload the package, which hasn't even been built yet ...

Comment: Hi, Martin. Does it mean that I have to make a complete project? But I've seen so many ppl do it with incomplete projects.